# Modular Addition general explanation

Tags: mathematics

This is an incredibly basic question, but basically I'm really struggling to understand what the "addition modulo 2" is and *why* is it used in quantum computing.

I've tried Wikipedia, endless QC lecture notes and forums, but everywhere they just **give for granted** that you know what the modular addition stands for... but I don't.

What *exactly* does a modulo 2 addition stand for? Where does the 2 come from? Can anyone please work out an example (rather than just give the result)?

For example, why does A⊕A⊕B=B?

For example again, I get what the CNOT gate does, and I understand how the bit-flipping matter works overall, but can someone please explain or direct me to a source on how this (0⊕b=b and 1⊕b=¬b) actually links to this modular addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly does a modulo 2 addition stand for?

It [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) that numbers are considered congruent (often stated as "equal" or "equal... mod 2") when they have the same remainder when divided by two.

For example, we write
$$
1 = 3 \;\text{mod }2
$$
since
$$
3 = 1 + 2 = 1 + 2n\;,
$$
where n is the integer 1.

For example, we write
$$
1 = 5 \;\text{mod }2
$$
since
$$
5 = 1 + 4 = 1 + 2n\;,
$$
where n is the integer 2.

For any number that is equal to $1 + 2n$, where $n$ is an integer, we say that number "equals 1 mod 2."

For any number that is equal to $0 + 2n$, where $n$ is an integer, we say that number "equals 0 mod 2."

$$
1 + 2n = 1 \;\text{mod }2 \\
0 + 2n = 0 \;\text{mod }2
$$

You can consider [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) with respect to *any* number. It just happens that mod 2 is useful when dealing with binary numbers, since that is the base of the number system.

---

> For example, why does A⊕A⊕B=B?

If $\oplus$ generally means addition, then the equality does not hold (in general). The equality holds when $\oplus$ means addition "mod 2," e.g., when $A$ and $B$ are bits. (Addition mod 2 on classical bits is equivalent to an XOR gate on classical bits.)

Regardless of whether $A$ is 0 or 1, we have:
$$
A\oplus A = 0\;\text{mod }2
$$
since (where $A=1$ and $n=1$)
$$
1 + 1 = 2 = 0 + 2 = 0 \;\text{mod }2
$$
and (where $A=0$ and $n=0$)
$$
0 + 0 = 0 = 0 + 0 = 0 \;\text{mod }2\;.
$$

Then, use that fact that modular arithmetic is associative and also
$$
0 \oplus B = B
$$
for any number B.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, it already helped so much!! 
Can I please ask how you obtained 0⊕B=B at the end?

Comment: 0 + B = B, zero is an identity element.

Comment: @user_confused if your $\oplus$ symbol stands for addition modulo two, then you can use the definition of modular arithmetic: Two things are equal "mod 2" if they differ by an integer multiple of 2. Clearly $B$ and $B+0$ are equal so they differ by an integer (zero) times 2 (i.e., they differ by zero).

Comment: If your symbol $\oplus$ stands for XOR, then you can look at the truth table for XOR. In particular: 0 XOR 0 is 0, 0 XOR 1 is 1, so for any $B$ (whether B is equal to 0 or equal to 1) we have 0 XOR B = B.

Comment: Ok I see I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To add to hft's great answer, addition modulo 2 is often used as a synonym for the bit-wise XOR function, as you can see from a truth table:

```
a   b    xor    a+b mod 2
-------------------------
0   0     0       0
0   1     1       1
1   0     1       1
1   1     0       0
```